# Wireless web authentication? (no WPA key)

Tags: raspbian, wireless

I picked up a wireless adapter for my Raspberry Pi and I would like to set it up on the network at work.

Our network is setup so that the SSID is broadcasted and users simply connect and then enter in a unique password via a web browser. Our server then authenticates them for 30 days or however long the password is good for and our users can simply connect at any time thereafter and use the internet until their password expires.

I have read the basic tutorials on setting up a WiFi adapter but will this work for a web based authentication service? What do I put in for the password if there is none required at the initial connection?

So far, this is what my config file looks like:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0

auto wlan0

iface wlan0 inet dhcp

wpa-ssid Honua

wpa-psk
```

Notice how the wpa-psk is just blank. Should it be "null" or "0" or something?

Answer (score 1):

The desktop wireless utility picked up the open wifi network and did all the work for me. It was very simple.

The authorization page worked just fine on Midori.

Comment: Hi, don't forget to mark this as an answer to the question :) Glad you found the solution you wanted!